# golang | Прочитать определенное кол-во байтов из net.Conn

Tags: golang

Есть сервер, на сервере listener

```
net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:9339")
```

Дальше это все accept'ится и настает черед читать байты из conn в количестве 7 штук. Я так и не понял как это делается, потому что bufio предлагает читать байты по одному или читать до определенного. Или читать по одному и надо?

Comment: ¿Почему по одному-то? Читайте пачку.

Comment: @user7860670 так в том и вопрос, как читать эту самую пачку?

Comment: У объекта `TCPConn`, который возвращает `Accept`, есть метод [Read](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.Read). Этот метод читает байты из соединения в байтовый массив. Возвращает число прочитанных байтов.